# What if a cosmic string is eaten by two black holes?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, string-theory, cosmic-string

What happens if you have a long cosmic string, each end of which is swallowed by a different blackhole, and the black holes have trajectories that will take them further away from eachother?
WHat happens next?

Comment: Surely cosmic strings (if they exist) are loops and so don’t have ends ??

Comment: Not all of them are loops, and even for the ones that are you can simply have different parts of the loop eaten by different strings.

Comment: This question is very vague. What does the poster expect will happen?

Comment: Note that this is roughly (but not quite) the situation described by the C-metric (an exact vacuum solution to the Einstein equation).

Comment: Can’t a cosmic string break up?